# Keras, IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement this simple neural network by Keras (Tensorflow beckend):

```
x_train = df_train[["Pclass", "Gender", "Age","SibSp", "Parch"]]
y_train = df_train ["Survived"]

x_test = df_test[["Pclass", "Gender", "Age","SibSp", "Parch"]]
y_test = df_test["Survived"]

y_train = y_train.values
y_test = y_test.values
```

But when I run this part:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=5, output_dim=1))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get this error: *IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds*. I am supposing that it is about the arguments in *model.fit(x_train, y_train)*. I have tried to pass these as numpy arrays by *.values*, but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras expects numpy arrays not pandas, so you need to convert all of the data that you are feeding into Keras APIs.. not just `y_train` and `y_test`

So:

```
x_train = x_train.values
y_train = y_train.values
x_test = x_test.values
y_test = y_test.values
```

Or

```
x_train = numpy.asarray(x_train)
y_train = numpy.asarray(y_train)
x_test = numpy.asarray(x_test)
y_test = numpy.asarray(y_test)
```

Comment: When I'm using  _.asarray_ I get this error _ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (571, 1)_. I had tried to use _.values_ before, but I got the same type of error

Comment: Have you tried as_matrix? (e.g. x_train.as_matrix())

Comment: Yes, but I get the same error. Now it works, with _.asarray_, after I changed loss function from "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"to "binary_crossentropy"